# How to schedule a task to call a URL

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, scheduled-task, background-process

I have an MVC app.  I have a controller that when called runs a background process to query Active Directory and updates the database.

http://myapp/BackgroundTask/Run

I want to run this on a schedule (daily) without opening a browser.  I see that there's a lot of third party solutions, is there something built in?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use the [Invoke-WebRequest](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest) cmdlet from Powershell.

In your task:

- Action: `Start a program`
- Program/script: `powershell.exe`
- Arguments: `-Command "Invoke-WebRequest http://myapp/BackgroundTask/Run"`

Comment: How to use Integrated Authentication?

Comment: Note: this only works in PowerShell 3 and up (to check your version, type `get-host` in powershell). In lower versions you'll need to call a separate powershell script, like in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17486205/call-an-url-with-scheduled-powershell-script

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use `cmd.exe` as follows:

- Action: `Start a program`
- Program/script: `cmd.exe`
- Arguments: `/c start "" http://myapp/BackgroundTask/Run &`

Comment: This variant opens a browser and this was explicitly excluded in the question.